# Why isn't there a field of mathematics that specifically studies nonlinear systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

There is linear algebra that is partially devoted to studying linear systems, vectors etc., but why isn't there such a developed field which focuses on nonlinear systems?

I've managed to find [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0609022.pdf) publication on the topic, but in the abstract it says "relatively new field". What are the greatest difficulties for development of that stream of mathematics?

Comment: While many kinds of "systems" have been studied with greater completion in linear cases than in nonlinear cases, it doesn't really amount to "nonlinear systems" being an undeveloped field as much as different kinds of "systems" have different successful techniques.  For example, most interesting polynomial systems are nonlinear (and a lot is known) while in differential equations the attacks on nonlinear cases are usually done by "linearizing" them in the neighborhood of a solution.

Comment: The systems of polynomial equations have been studied for years, to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_equation): "The study of algebraic equations is probably as old as mathematics"

Comment: The paper you linked above says (in part), "[I]n this paper we restrict consideration to non-linear, but polynomial equations."  It appears to be motivated by ways to evaluate *discriminants* and [*resultants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), ideas that were developed late in the $19$th century.  Perhaps clarification and a tag should be added to reflect a focus on polynomial systems?

Comment: Maybe algebraic geometry could be considered as the field the question refers to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one, and it is called "algebraic geometry".

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the Wikipedia article, [Algebraic Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry)?